# How to re-map Action implementation class in struts.xml?

Tags: java, struts2

How do I inject the implementation class of a action in struts.xml from struts2.xml?

Suppose struts.xml looks like the following:

```
<struts>
    <action name="EnginesList" class="example.EnginesListAction">
        <result name="*">viewengines.jsp</result>
    </action>
</struts>
```

Then I wanted to achieve: when struts2.xml exists(or is not blank), then the class-mappings in struts2.xml overrides those in struts.xml. So if I have the following definition, at runtime EnginesList is mapped to example.EnginesListAction2 instead of example.EnginesListAction.

```
// struts.xml:
<struts>    
    <action name="EnginesList" class="example.EnginesListAction">
        <result name="*">viewengines.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <include file="struts2.xml" />
</struts>

// struts2.xml
<struts>    
    <action name="EnginesList" class="example.EnginesListAction2">
        <result name="*">viewengines.jsp</result>
    </action>
</struts>
```

This seems not working due to name conflict. So what's the best way of achieving my end goal?

---

**Background added**:

1. Team-A develops and maintains struts.xml. My team(team-B) uses the codebase of team-A and deploys it in a separate data center.
2. Team-B needs to have some actions be mapped to different classes. However we cannot directly modify it in struts.xml since it will change the behavior of Team-A's service.
3. So what I wanted is to have a separate file(struts2.xml) whose class-mappings can override those in struts.xml. No changes in action package name. No changes in JSP code. This struts2.xml will be deployed ONLY in team-B's data center.

Comment: What is your *end goal*? Why do you need this?

Comment: @AleksandrM struts.xml is maintained by team A, and our team(team B) is not allowed to modify class-mappings in struts.xml, so we have to inject class-mappings from a separate file. If this injection works, then team-A starts their server with only struts.xml loaded, and team-B starts their server with both struts.xml and struts2.xml loaded.

Comment: @zzhang Editing a question you can **add details under EDIT:** mark, and not remove important content from it, trying to modify the question in such way.

Comment: You can use DI container such as spring. There is S2 spring plugin which allows actions to be created and autowired by spring.

Comment: @RomanC I removed no content from my original question. My modification is add-only.

Comment: @zzhang: When do you solve your problem you can post solution as an answer if you want to. +1 Good question.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way you could do this, is by using multiple ( separate ) struts configuration files and importing them into your main `struts.xml` file.

In your case rename `struts.xml` to `struts1.xml`. Include these two file in your main `struts.xml`

```
<include file="struts1.xml"></include>
<include file="struts2.xml"></include>
```

I am not sure about the order of imports of these file, so cannot comment on whether mappings in 2nd file will shadow the mappings in 1st or vice versa. Try that for yourself to decide which file must be included first.

For more information regarding including configuration refer [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/include-configuration.html).

Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-include-multiple-struts-configuration-files/) link for a full example.